# I do not understand why my database is not updating with new models

Tags: python, mysql, django

New to python/django. I have a model, "Comments", that i created. I have a view where i want to create a new comment model. When i do this (click the submit button((actually "Create" button))), i get:

```
ProgrammingError at /reviews/ (1146, "Table 'my_app.my_app_comment' doesn't     
exist")
```

models.py

```
class Comments(models.Model):
     comment_text = models.CharField(max_length=600, default="None")
     recipe = models.ForeignKey('cookbook.BaseRecipe', related_name='val1')
```

views.py

```
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Comments
    fields = ['comment_text']
    template_name = 'commentcreate.html'
    success_url = 'commentcreate.html'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', CommentCreate.as_view(), name='comment')
]
```

part of commentcreate.html file

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

I thought that this table (the one it says is missing) would be created automatically by django.

Comment: You need to run `manage.py makemigrations`/`migrate`..

Comment: have you done syncdb? my bad you are using new version you need to 

python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: i tried doing both the make migrations and migrate. It tells me their is nothing to update

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply *migrations* for new models. In your project's folder, run

```
manage.py makemigrations [application_name]
manage.py migrate [application_name]
```

Here `[application_name]` is optional (you may substitute it with the actual modified Django application's name, or omit it).

If you're using Python3, you may need to run `python3 manage.py ...` instead of just `manage.py ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you haven't added your app `my_app` to `settings.py`. Update your `settings.py` like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i did not have a migrations folder with the **init**.py file in my application. Once i created these two things, everything seems to work now. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call your app specifically:

1. Include the app name in the settings.py
2. Run `python manage.py makemigrations yourappname`
3. `python manage.py migrate --no-initial-data YOURAPPNAME`
4. Check your migration table in database to see if you have already some migrations for that app.
5. In case nothing worked, or you had problems with migrations, you can delete all those entries in the table, delete the migration folder and run (1) again.